# Central superscripts on \bigcup

Tags: superscripts

The `\bigcup` symbol allows you to write an upper bound (`\bigcup_{lb}^{ub}`) that will be centered on the top of the cup.
For my problem I'm defining a modified version of the union operator that I'd like to indicate ad `\widetilde{\bigcup}`, but I couldn't obtain the tilde between the cup and the upper bound

`\widetilde {\bigcup_{\gamma = 1}^{n}}` : puts the tilde above the n

`\widetilde {\bigcup}_{\gamma = 1}^{n}` : the upper bound is not centered

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand exactly what you want the result to look like.  Is there an image somewhere you could point us to?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the easiest way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\wbigcup}{\mathop{\widetilde{\bigcup}}\displaylimits}

\begin{document}
\[
\wbigcup_{i=1}^n A_i
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that `\displaylimits` is not really needed, but clarity is important.

[image]